# JQuery Mobile Form helpers using the Play Framework

Tags: jquery-mobile, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I am trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/2.0.x/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app) play-authenticate module with the mobile side of my application. I want to use JQuery mobile for each of the pages instead of Twitter Bootstrap. So I've created a separate view and I've just set up a basic index and I am trying to get the login page to work first. The login page takes a form as its arguement and I'm just wondering if there is a way to use the scala form helpers in play 2.0.* with JQuery Mobile.

My basic login page so far:

```
@(loginForm: Form[_])

@import helper._

@main(Messages("playauthenticate.login.title"),"login") {
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="textinput1">
                        Your Email
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="email" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="textinput2">
                        Your Password
                    </label>
                    <input name="" id="textinput2" placeholder="" value="" type="password" />
                </div>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page1">
                    Login Now
                </a>
                <h4>
                    Or login with a different service:
                </h4>
                      @* Display list of available providers *@
                      @_providerPartial(skipCurrent=false)
                <a data-role="button" data-transition="slidedown" href="routes.Application.index()">
                    Home
                </a>
            </div>
}
```

[This](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/2.0.x/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/login.scala.html) is how it looks using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and... no.

As you showed us jQueryMobile has its specific markup for form, so built-in `helpers` of Play doesn't fit it in any way...

You have two solutions and choice between this you want to use belongs to you:

- If you have just few forms, write them with common HTML according to [JQM's specification](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/forms/).
- Otherwise, if you plan to use lot of forms in many places you'll do better if you'll... write own [`field constructors`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaFormHelpers).

Of course if you'll decide to go with second approach it will be great if you'll decide to share it with others :)